# MySQL Query to check if UNIX timestamp is not Monday

Tags: mysql, sql, unix-timestamp

I have a MySQL table with 100000 rows.

Each row only has 1 column named `unixtime` containing a different unix-timestamp. Data type is `long`.

What MySQL query would you use to remove all the rows except those where unix-timestamp is Monday?

Monday in MySQL Server's default time zone.

Comment: Do you mean Monday in MySQL Server's default time zone or in some other time zone?

Comment: What have you tried?  This is a pretty direct application of MySQL date/time functions.

Comment: Please check this https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Comment: Monday in MySQL Server's default time zone.

Answer (score 2):

Use the functions FROM_UNIXTIME and DAYNAME

1. FROM_UNIXTIME converts a unixtime stamp into a DATETIME format.
2. DAYNAME needs a DATETIME format to get the days name. Why function DAYNAME instead off the DAYOFWEEK function? `DAYNAME(...) <> 'Monday'` is more clear to read  then `DAYOFWEEK(..) <> 2`

It's not clear from the question if you want to filter out the records or actually delete the records from the table
So ive included both the select query to filter out the records and delete to really delete those records from the table.

**SELECT Query**

```
SELECT
 *
FROM 
 table 
WHERE
 DAYNAME(FROM_UNIXTIME(unixtime)) <> 'Monday'
```

**Delete query**

```
DELETE 
 *
FROM 
 table
WHERE
  DAYNAME(FROM_UNIXTIME(unixtime)) <> 'Monday'
```

Answer (score 1):

When you say "Remove" i am not sure if you want to delete the from the table or exclude them from a SELECT so I have included both

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable
WHERE DAYOFWEEK(FROM_UNIXTIME(YourColumn)) = 2

DELETE
FROM YourTable
WHERE DAYOFWEEK(FROM_UNIXTIME(YourColumn)) <> 2
```

Comment: The delete query should also use `<> 2` instead off `= 2` right?

Comment: Actually it was my SELECT that was wrong. To "remove those rows except where the timestamp is Monday" needs an =

Comment: "MySQL Query to check if UNIX timestamp is not Monday" that is clearly a `<> 'Monday'` well the question isn't that clear..

Comment: Yes the title is a slight contradiction of the question text. I went with what was in the question text "What MySQL query would you use to remove all the rows except those where unix-timestamp is Monday?" Perhaps the OP will clarify